# NLTK PunktSequenceTokenizer return type or a way to use it faster in an iterative function?

Tags: php, python-3.x, nltk

Within my PHP function, I am calling a Python script like this:

```
 $foo = exec("python tokenize.py $bar");
```

The problem is, now I have built a function that executes the command above iteratively and it takes more than five minutes to finish, because of the code I use below:

```
train_text = state_union.raw("1963-Johnson.txt") 
custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)
```

The operation of training my PST takes some time even for one of the shortest corpora in the state_union package.

I tried to store the output in a plain txt file but I cannot find the return type in the documentation [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). I guess it is an iterator like everything else in the package, but I've tried to convert the iterator to the list and failed miserably.

**The questions are:**

**1. What is the return type of the PunktSentenceTokenizer and can I store it?**

**2. Will reading it from the .txt file or any other source be faster than training it over and over when executing my PHP program?**

**3. Do you have any other idea how to use PST so it remains trained over the same portion of text so I can use it with my script faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html) it?

```
import pickle
... # other imports and stuff
custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)
pickle.dump(custom_sent_tokenizer, open( "save.p", "wb" ))
```

Now you can easily load the trained tokenizer in another call or script:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.load(open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
<nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer object at 0x00000000023B9EB8>
```

Comment: Hmm, it clearly works, but I cannot sense any significant speed increase. Do you think it is faster to PST tokenize using "1963-Johnson.txt" iteratively or to load the pickle file every time? (~1800 lines of pickle format)

Comment: The advantage that you get from `pickle` is that you have to train your PST only once and that you can store it for all future use cases. I'm convinced that loading the pickle object is faster then training the PST from scratch, especially for large training texts!